# Joining unrelated models and filter the queryset

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have the following Models I would like to join:

`Datapoint`

```
class Datapoint(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Composition', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    value = models.IntegerField(db_column='Value')  # Field name made lowercase.
```

`Composition`

```
class Composition(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

`DataComponent`

```
class Datacomponent(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Composition_ID', null=True, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    components = models.ForeignKey(Components, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Components_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    componentvalue = models.FloatField(db_column='ComponentValue')  # Field name made lowercase.
```

And finally, `Component`

```
class Components(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Each datapoint contains a foreign key to the composition table. `Datapoint` and `Composition` tables are hence related. Each composition has many components which is linked by composition field in Datacomponent table which also contains components foreign key to the Component table.

The end goal is to build a list of Datapoint objects filtered by a particular component value in Datacomponents table.

For instance lets say we have a number of datapoints. If we just have 2 Compositions A and B. A contains 2 elements AA and BB with values being 30 and 50 respectively. B contains 3 elements AA BBB and CC with values  40, 50, and 60 respectively. One example query in this scenario would be - Fetch all datapoints with Component AA's value more than 30.

Since Datacomponent is not directly linked with Datapoint, I am not sure how to combine these two models. Currently I am trying to build this in `get_object_list` of `tastypie` library.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the relationships through as many levels as you like. Remember to always start from the class whose objects you need. For your example query, it would look something like:

```
Datapoint.objects.filter(
    composition__datacomponent__component_value__gte=30,
    composition__datacomponent__components__name='AA'
)
```

Comment: Didn't know it was this simple! Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: One more question, I have multiple components__name and each of the component values must be greater than or equal to some value (lets say 30 in this case). Since all the tables will be joined, how do I only get the datapoints with composition whose each component value is gte 30?